# about software architecture i think

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, command-line-interface

I have 4 levels in a project:

- `view`
- `{placeholder}`
- `controllers`
- `models`

The level `{placeholder}` is responsible for cleaning up user inputs and classifying them multiple times, after classifying them it heads towards one of the `controllers`.

**Questions:**

1. What type of architecture is this?
2. How would I call that level `{placeholder}`?

**Context:**
The user only enters something via console.
That input goes as follows:

- form 1: `[expression]`
- form 2: `[command] [arguments] [expression]`

So that `{placeholder}` layer takes that and sends the `[expression]`, whether it's in form 1 or 2, to classify it according to its way and associate it with the appropriate object at the `model` level.

On the other hand, if it's in form 2, besides having associated the `[expression]` with the `model`, it's now necessary to associate the `[command] [arguments]` with a method of the `controller` to do something to `<expression>`.

And finally, display a result on the screen, the expression can be whatever the user wants, the commands and arguments are already predefined.

I have read about it but i have a lot of different possibilities answers for `{placeholder}` layer:

- communication layer
- middleware
- proxy
- router
- controller of controllers
- decorator
- control layer
- input handler
- input controller

There are so many different concepts that I don't know where to direct my doubt.

Comment: Are you using level and layer interchangeably? Are the communication restricted between the layers (liker only upper layer can call lower and not in the other way around)?

Comment: BTW why is it important how to call that `{placeholder}` layer/level/tier?

Answer (score 0):

> What type of architecture is this?

It's Model-View-Controller (MVC), which is the essential design pattern for ***interactive** components*.  There are indeed countless variations, e.g. MVVM and MVP and others (not to mention "MVC for the web", which is not really MVC proper), but those are all derived from MVC and are in fact specializations/simplifications of MVC.

> I have a lot of different possibilities answers for {placeholder} layer

There is no standard name for that, I call it "Driver", anyway it is simply an orchestration/plumbing wrapper and (IMO) you do end up needing one as soon as things are not totally simple, so you do are on the right track.  Just one objection/caution: the MVC pattern is *not* linear, it is a triangle (and then you can see what's the real point of it: breaking a circular dependency...)

Here is a concrete example of such an architecture (it is *very* old code of mine, please bear with some naivety, anyway just the overall architectural idea is the point here): [TicTacToe 1.2.B / Docs](http://julio.diegidio.name/CaseStudies/TicTacToe/Docs/TicTacToe.1.2.B.pre/TicTacToe.1.2.B.pre.htm)